# How to enable Spring Boot to display a list of files under a directory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a folder structure /data/reports on a file system, which contains all reports.
How can I configure a SpringBoot application to serve the contents of this file sytem.

Currently I have tried few options, but none working

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Value(value = "${spring.resources.static-locations:#{null}}")
private String fileSystem;

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
    .addResourceHandler("/data/reports/**")
    .addResourceLocations(fileSystem)
    .setCachePeriod(3600)
    .resourceChain(true)
    .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
}
}
```

and in application.properties I have defined

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:///data/reports
server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.listings=true
```

But in both cases, when I try

```
 http://host:port/application/data/reports
```

I'm getting 404

What am I missing ?

Based on the suggestions given, I realized that one mistake I'm doing is to access the reports via

```
http://host:port/application/data/reports
```

instead of

```
http://host:port/data/reports
```

if I use application in the request, those calls will go through RequestDispatcher and will try to find for a matching RequestMapping, which does not exist. I think I'm convinced so far.

But the problem I'm seeing now is, I'm getting SocketTimeoutException while trying to read from the resource listed in the URL. I had put some breakpoints in Spring source "ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java"

```
protected void writeContent(Resource resource, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    try {
        InputStream in = resource.getInputStream(); //It is timing out here
        try {
            StreamUtils.copy(in, outputMessage.getBody());
        }
        catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            // ignore, see SPR-13620
        }
```

The resource is a small text file with 1 line "Hello World". Yet it is timing out.

The resource in the above class is a FileUrlResource opened on file:///c:/data/reports/sample.txt

On the other hand, I tried to read that resource as

```
  File file = new File("c:/data/reports/sample.txt");
    System.out.println(file.exists());
    URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream(); //This works
```

Thanks

Comment: Java SE already has APIs regarding this. This should help; https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-folders-from-a-folder-in-java

Comment: I agree Java SE has that API. But that is not what I'm look. Does SpringBoot serve such listings out of the box through configuration ? The example I mentioned above is what I referred from Spring boot docs and other examples found. But that is not serving my purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure but it may require to provide public access to this path in your web config. Should be something like this  .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/data/reports/**").permitAll().  I have a working example of the Spring Boot app that serves PDF reports secured with JWT. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks let me try that option and revert back

Comment: I have added    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("c://reports//reports/**")
            .permitAll();
    }  but its not working yet